# Is there any difference between dual boot Ubuntu and and windows system and a Stand alone Ubuntu system?

Tags: installation, 13.04

I have a dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 system(not wubi)and I wanted to know is there any difference when we install Ubuntu by erasing whole hard disk(Stand alone) and when we dual boot it by giving it available free space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer:

Dual booting works very well, but if it was me I would go stand alone.

If you need the ability to run Windows software natively, then dual boot is the way to go; otherwise stick with stand alone.

As far as performance, there would be no difference between dual booting and stand alone, unless you use WUBI to install Ubuntu, then there will be a performance issue.  Now, **my personal opinion**, generally speaking Ubuntu will perform better on the same machine than Windows.

Comment: thanks for reply but I want know that is there any performance difference between the two or they are same.

Comment: Well, you didn't specify that in your question.

Comment: Sorry.I unaccepted it by-mistake..

Comment: I have added a bit about performance.

Comment: Glad to help. You're welcome :)